# R ggpubbr stat_compare means not adding correct p-values?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

```
ggpubr::compare_means(deltaCt ~ Sample, data = all_delta_Ct_data, 
              group.by = "Gene", method = "t.test", p.adjust.method = "fdr")

  Gene   .y.     group1 group2        p  p.adj p.format p.signif method
  <chr>  <chr>   <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr> 
1 Gabra1 deltaCt CORT   VEH    0.00153  0.0031 0.0015   **       T-test
2 FKBP5  deltaCt CORT   VEH    0.00874  0.012  0.0087   **       T-test
3 Gabra5 deltaCt CORT   VEH    0.0155   0.016  0.0155   *        T-test
4 Gabra2 deltaCt CORT   VEH    0.000498 0.002  0.0005   ***      T-test

p1 <- ggplot(all_delta_Ct_data_plot, aes(x = Gene, y = delta_mean, fill= Sample)) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), colour='black', stat='identity')

p1 + ggpubr::stat_compare_means(aes(group = Sample), label = "p.signif")
```

[image]

p.signif shows up as ns - which it isn't! how do i fix this? I do have error bars and an adjusted theme but this is the pared down bar plot for simplicity.

edit dput:

```
> dput(all_delta_Ct_data_plot)
structure(list(Sample = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("VEH", "CORT"), class = "factor"), Gene = c("FKBP5", 
"Gabra1", "Gabra2", "Gabra5", "FKBP5", "Gabra1", "Gabra2", "Gabra5"
), delta_mean = c(6.51069005333333, 9.23713970666667, 1.33728727, 
2.13134956666667, 5.40629005333333, 10.8342940033333, 2.96229172, 
3.98792394), sd = c(0.222958948184453, 0.148270196392776, 0.0217820593062569, 
0.467260230368909, 0.0666218747325843, 0.243214990198787, 0.0864332043296873, 
0.605507533051752), delta_sd = c(0.0497106925755177, 0.0219840511383523, 
0.000474458107621294, 0.218332122884406, 0.00443847419288415, 
0.0591535314573962, 0.00747069881069747, 0.366639372582418), 
    delta_n = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), delta_sem = c(0.0287004817400779, 
    0.0126924978426062, 0.000273928516154355, 0.126054109920054, 
    0.00256255427005287, 0.0341523073104447, 0.0043132099693908, 
    0.211679340455975)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Edit2:
Info from [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/76-add-p-values-and-significance-levels-to-ggplots/#compare-more-than-two-groups).
-> Multiple grouping variables

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: It may be that it's using a different test method compared to `compare_means`. Perhaps  use the same arguments to `stat_compare_means` as you did to `compare_means` and you'll get the same results.

Comment: @alanocallaghan i've tried that but I can't get that to work without getting an aes() missing error - i'm following the instructions linked in the 2nd edit

Comment: You are running `ggpubr::stat_compare_means()` on the summary data `all_delta_Ct_data_plot`, not the full data that are creating the significance values, `all_delta_Ct_data`. You didnt provide that dataset, but I imagine its quite easy to fix